# How can I add a public_html directory into a user's home directory?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, web-server

I have Apache 2.2 installed. I want to set up my server so that for each user I create there is a public_html directory in which that user can put it's web content. Now, of course, making the directory is just a matter of `mkdir`, but how do I tell Apache to "watch" over that directory's contents (and serve them if required)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out "mod_userdir" (you should have a .conf somewhere in /etc/, or have it in httpd.conf/apache.conf).

Basically all you have to do is to enable the mod, and it should work with the default configuration.